# Can a Pathfinder Vampire store blood for later use?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I know it's kind of vague in terms of what kind of vampire archetype i.e. Dhampir and nosferatu, but I'm mostly just curious:

A. Can you drink it from a cup or container if it's fresh, and what's the shelf-life?

B. What could you store it in?

C. Obviously drinking typically kills or damages, providing some frame of reference as to how much blood is drunk, so "How much blood is enough blood to satiate?"

D. What would be *ideal* to store it in? I.e. should I just use a waterskin, some glass vials, etc. I don't want to have to be like "I drink six vials of blood" because that's how much is needed to satiate or something.

E. What would be ideal in terms of drinking it 'in secret'. I don't want characters who aren't the DM to know (it'll be a bitch to hide, but I have to at least make an attempt obviously) Glass vials are kinda... made out of glass, and imagine waterskins are at least a little messy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the shelf life of blood (which is a question for medical experts, not us) and depends on knowing whether vampires need to drink blood directly from the vein (which no known Pathfinder supplement explains). The best answer, and the only reliable answer you'll get, will come from your GM.

Comment: "Hunger" is an optional rule - not a mandatory one. Source: Pathfinder Player Companion: Blood of the Night © 2012, Paizo Publishing, LLC; Author: Tork Shaw.

Comment: Not entirely relevant, but thanks for the background info :p